# Transposing substrings around comma in R

Tags: r

I have data frame containing a list of countries. Countries such as the People's Republic of China are formatted like 'China, People's Republic of'.

E.g. 'Congo, Democratic Republic of the', 'Macedonia, Republic of', etc.

For each country string in this format, I'd like to tranpose its name and its 'title' around the comma, such that it reads as it normally would, so,

'Congo, Democratic Republic of the', would be transformed to 'Democratic Republic of the Congo'.

Thanks.

Comment: `paste0(sub(".*, ", "", country), " ", sub(", .*", "", country))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `sub` and grouping a regular expression.  Each set of parenthesis constitutes a group and they can be recalled with `\\1` `\\2` etc. In this case we group the first word with `(\\w+)` and move it behind the group of the second or more words grouped by `(.*)` and we don't need the comma in the middle so it is not included in a group.

```
str <- c('Congo, Democratic Republic of the', 'Macedonia, Republic of', 'etc')
sub("(\\w+), (.*)","\\2 \\1",str)
# [1] "Democratic Republic of the Congo" "Republic of Macedonia"            "etc"
```

Comment: And to apply this to the 'country' column in my data frame, I would use lapply?

Comment: If you just want to sub you can do: `df$country <- sub("(\\w+), (.*)","\\2 \\1",df$country)` where `df$country` is the column of your data frame with the countries as strings.